# How to get the application metrics in Docker container and Kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have dockerize the microservice app and now using Kubernetes.

Sometimes container is running in `healthy` state but there is a problem in microservice app so I have to get the app metrics.

Is it possible to get the metrics from outside the container/pod?

Comment: Kubernetes provides his own metric service https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server. If you need to inspect the application metrics, I suppose you are using Observable pattern, You can query the endpoint with applications like Prometheus for example.

Comment: is that possible to get in variables like that

Comment: and any idea about docker?

Comment: You could use cAdvisor (https://github.com/google/cadvisor) which was the first software used by Kubernetes to provide containers performance

Comment: I didn't get your comment about `variables` can you explain it just out of interest?

Comment: like instead of using monitoring tool  is that possible to get any of the application metrics using env variable

Comment: for example if i want to get thread got killed in application from outside the container

Comment: I think `env` variables is not the right approach. You cannot query env variables from the host, you can only see the envs have been set during the run phases. I added my complete answers hope you find it helpfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest designing your application using the Observability patter, basically, you will create a path, `/metrics` for example, and you will hit this path every time you need the application's info. The path is populated of all the information you need (killed threads for example)   This approach could be called `withe box monitoring`: the application knows his status. Then you can either use tools like Prometheus to query the path and create alerts or just hit the path retrieving information which are exposed in the format you want to (json, yml, ecc). The path will be reached using a simple web server, may be integrated into the application as well. Exposing the container port `80` you can basically run a simple `curl http://<container name | localhost>/metrics` getting all the information you need. 
You can find a bunch of library you can integrate into your application.

Comment: thanks and one more question my idea is to change the replica count based on the applicaion server so with your solution is that possible?   if you don't mind can you tell this

Comment: It is possible and you have more than one solution. If you create a kind of automation (so that I can suggest you use a container manager like Kubernetes) you could create a simple docker application, or either extend yours,  that will communicate with docker-daemon REST API mounting the docker socket within the "scale application" is running into. Not sure if you are able to scale up/down containers, you may want to check API docs. Instead, if you want to create an external let's say bash script, you can use `docker scale` to scale your application after hitting the `/metrics` endpoint.

Comment: sorry I'm new to these things can you tell which api docs i want to refer and getting confusing with new term like docker scale   can you tell in detail if possible

Comment: Sure. This is how to scale using `docker cli` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_scale/ and these are the `docker API` https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/. The first one is the command you would run to scale manually the service. The latter are pure docker REST API you would consume looking for libraries written in your preferred languages

Answer (score 1):

To monitor your cluster you can use [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus). Additionally you can setup [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) and get your pod metrics by running

```
kubectl top pod --namespace=NAMESPACE
```

Comment: any possibilites without using monitoring tool?